# (React-native) How to take a result from an async function in componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, asynchronous

I am new to React-Native.
I am trying to `cropImage` and with the result, `cropped.uri`, I want to `storeData` of objects of `{key : keyIndex++, productname: object.object, expiryDate: 8, image: cropped.uri}`
Below is my code block.

I cannot send the result from `cropImage` to the line before `{key : keyIndex++, productname: object.object, expiryDate: 8, image: cropped.uri}`. It prints the right result inside of `cropImage` but if I print it outside the function, it says 'undefined'.

I tried constructor and states, but it still prints 'undefined'
I think it is a timing problem.. but have no idea. Help please.

```
export default class AddItems extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    const endpoint = `https://foodsaver.cognitiveservices.azure.com/`;
    const key = `89625116fce1a`;
    const apiPath = `${endpoint}/vision/v2.0/analyze`;

    const storeData = async (value)=>{
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(value))
        } catch(e){
            console.log("error occured during store data", e)
        }
    }
    const readData =  async () => {
        try {
            const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("items")
            if(data != null){
                // console.log(JSON.parse(data))
                return JSON.parse(data)
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }catch(e){
            console.log("error occured during reading data", e)
        }
    }
    const cropImage = async (object) => {
        cropData = {
            originX:object.rectangle.x,
            originY:object.rectangle.y,
            width:object.rectangle.w,
            height:object.rectangle.h
        }
        try{
            await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(items.uri, [{crop:cropData}], {compress: 1})
            .then(cropped => {
                // console.debug(cropped.uri), //ok
                object.image = cropped.uri
              })
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log('Error caught in this.cropImage:', error)
        }
    }
    
    const fd = new FormData();
    var items = {
        uri: "file:///Users/Repositories/FoodSaver/assets/items.jpeg",
        
        name: "items.jpeg",
        type: "image/jpeg"
    }
    fd.append("file", items)
    axios.post(
        apiPath,
        fd,
        {
            params: {
                language : "en",
                visualFeatures: "Objects"
            },
            headers : {
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : key,
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        }
    ).then(({data:{objects}})=>{
        const res = objects.map(object=>{
            if (object.object === "Fruit") {
                // want to add image here!
                return {key : keyIndex++, productname: object.object, expiryDate: 8, image: cropImage(object).image}
            }
            return {key : keyIndex++, productname: object.object, expiryDate: 10, image: cropImage(object).image}
        })
        readData().then((data)=>{
            const listOfObject = [...data, ...res]
            storeData(listOfObject)
            Alert.alert(`Items are added to My Fridge!`)
        })
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.log("error", e));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two parts to the problem:

1. cropImage doesn't return anything
2. not waiting for asynchronous behaviour to finish executing

**cropImage doesn't return anything**

there is no return value from cropImage so

`image: cropImage(object).image` is effectively the same as `image: undefined.image`

Let's return the result of manipulateAsync

```
try{
  return ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(items.uri, [{crop:cropData}], {compress: 1})
}
```

**not waiting for asynchronous behaviour to finish executing**

You have another issue related to async execution which you picked up on.

cropImage has async code and you depend on its result so you'll have to use the await syntax when executing cropImage to ensure it finishes executing.

`return {key : keyIndex++, productname: object.object, expiryDate: 8, image: await cropImage(object).uri}`

Comment: I tried to return the value from cropImage before, but it still said undefined. I think it is a problem related to timing, async and await as you said. However, when I just tried  'return await {key : keyIndex++, productname: object.object, expiryDate: 8, image: cropImage(object).uri}' and it says 'Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (97:27)'

Comment: you need to mark it with await because this makes the execution wait for the promise (result of cropImage) to resolve. the error message you’re getting is telling you that you need to mark the function scope with the async keyword. it’s a .map callback so the syntax will look a bit funky objects.map(async (object) =>{{...})